# how to hide empty fields of post category description?

Tags: posts, categories, theme-development, description

I am creating one website from scratch, where I have to display Category description, how to hide the div, if there is no description written in backend for the post category?

my codes are:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8 mx-auto py-5">
        <?php echo nl2br($qo->description) ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to hide the entire row, if there is no description written in backend for the post category.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the div with a if condition like this. It should do the job!

```
<?php if($qo->description):?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8 mx-auto py-5">
        <?php echo nl2br($qo->description) ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```